# Get the hidden div element html content with the style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a hidden `div` and I am trying to get this div with the styles. When I append this div with the below code it is getting appended with out the styles. Please suggest some other way.

```
    var warningMessage = $('#warningDiv').html()


function postSettings() {
    var frm_data = $("#MyForm").serialize();
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "path",
            data: frm_data,
            success: function (successData) {
                var warningMessage = $('#warningDiv').html();
                **$(warningMessage).insertAfter("#MyDiv"); // This is not showing the warning message with css styles .** 
            },

        });
}
```

This gives the HTML without style, but I want the styles as well and need to append this with another div dynamically.  This is the div:

```
<div class="note note-warning" id="warningDiv" style="display:none">
    <div class="block-warning">
        <h4 class="block"> <i class="demo-icon icon-attention-1 fa"></i> Warning! Some Header Goes Here</h4>
        <p> test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how are you appending it ??

Comment: I am appending like this - $(warningMessage).insertAfter("#MySecondDiv");

Comment: can you provide complete code in order to identify exact problem?

Comment: You mean you want the `"style="diplay:none"` to be inserted aswell? Or the whole content that you posted ? What does it returns now, and what would you like it to return ?

Comment: is there any `css` to `class` `note` and `note-warning`

Comment: Yes . There are css styles for the DIV .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

For testing purpose I have removed 'display:none' property from the div 'warningDiv'.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {

        });
        function postSettings() {
            $($("#warningDiv").prop('outerHTML')).insertAfter("#MyDiv");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="note note-warning" id="warningDiv" style="color: red;">
        <div class="block-warning">
            <h4 class="block"><i class="demo-icon icon-attention-1 fa"></i>Warning! Some Header Goes Here</h4>
            <p>test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" onclick="postSettings()" value="Click here to call postSettings()" />
        <div id="MyDiv">MyDiv</div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have removed 'display:none' property from newly created div.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {

        });
        function postSettings() {
            $($("#warningDiv").prop('outerHTML')).insertAfter("#MyDiv").show();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="note note-warning" id="warningDiv" style="display: none;">
        <div class="block-warning">
            <h4 class="block"><i class="demo-icon icon-attention-1 fa"></i>Warning! Some Header Goes Here</h4>
            <p>test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" onclick="postSettings()" value="Click here to call postSettings()" />
        <div id="MyDiv">MyDiv</div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: what is warningDiv1 here?

Comment: We can not add same id to multiple elements/controls so I have added dummy id for newly created div.

Comment: this is not working for me ..can you give the code ? . Please refer my question and try this

Comment: Could you please provide your full code (Like: How and where are you appending 'warningMessage') ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using bellow

```
    var warningMessage = $('#warningDiv');
    var rowData='<div class="note note-warning" id="warningDiv"style="display:none"> <div class="block-warning"><h4 class="block"> <i class="demo-icon icon-attention-1 fa"></i> Warning! Some Header Goes Here</h4><p> test</p></div></div>';
warningMessage.append(rowData);
```

Comment: This will work but I dont want to keep the html in a variable . Sometimes my html will be having more than 20 lines.

Comment: then you can append it directly like this  warningMessage.append('<div class="note note-warning" id="warningDiv"style="display:none"> <div class="block-warning"><h4 class="block"> <i class="demo-icon icon-attention-1 fa"></i> Warning! Some Header Goes Here</h4><p> test</p></div></div>');

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var warningMessage = $('#warningDiv').get(0).outerHTML;
```